# Weird display issues when playing videos on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, video, vlc

After about a year of running Ubuntu 12.04, we've suddenly developed a bug that affects video-playing. Everything in the display works fine, except when we try watching a video (in either VLC and Movie Player), at which point things get messed up. Here are two example screenshots:

[image]

[image]

There seem to be two symptoms here. Sometimes we'll see a strange overlay of the last screen we closed, and sometimes all of the colors shift sideways. Sometimes both. It's not entirely consistent, meaning that sometimes the video will decide to work fine.

As mentioned, this problem occurs over at least two video players and many video files which worked before today. We're running Ubuntu 12.04, our graphics card is a Bonaire XT [Radeon HD 7790/8770].
It's worth noting that the problem may have been caused by a standard update earlier in the day.